# How to append some text in a span properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a post box with '#' tag feature. My HTML code till now

```js
$("#textinput").click(function() {
  setCursor("textinput", 0);
  $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
})

$("#textinput").keyup(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e['originalEvent']['keyCode'];
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  if (keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 40) {

  } else {
    var x = $(this).text();
    x = x.replace("Write HEre", "");
    var len = x.length;
    if (len == 1) {
      if (keyCode == 51) {
        $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post highlighted-textbox" ></span>');
      } else {
        $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post normal-textbox" ></span>');
      }

    } else {
      if (keyCode == 51) {
        $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post highlighted-textbox" ></span>');
      }
    }

    var items = $(".text-post");
    var tot = items.length;
    var span = $(items[tot - 1]);
    span.append(e['originalEvent']['key']);

    $(this).html($("#show-text"));
    //Funtion for setting cursor
    setCursor2();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 50px; border: 1px solid black;" id="textinput" contenteditable>
  <div class="post-placeholder">Write HEre</div>
  <div id="show-text"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I am typing `hi` it's showing output like this:

```
<span contenteditable="" class="text-post normal-textbox">hii</span>
```

For the first key press it's working fine, but for further keypresses it's appending twice. It's look like this in the source code:

```
<span contenteditable="" class="text-post normal-textbox">
"hi"
"i"
</span>
```

Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any better way to do so. If yes,please let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a div instead of a input field?

Comment: Because I want to create this such a way ,when someone  will type '#' ,then the text style will be different until he type space. If I use input it will be hard to style  the input value differently​.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few tricky parts. The reason that you're getting duplicated characters is that your code has input character itself and also an appended character. So a provided character appears where your cursor was and a new character will be appended(test after move your cursor to the front). You can ignore the provided character by bind your function to `keydown` event and call `preventDefault` to prevent escalating the input event.
Then, why this does not happen for first few times? You have not only text but also `div` element within your `#textinput` element. When you get the text of this element, there will be two linebreaks but you only replace `Write HEre` so the length is not 1 even for the first time.
And for the last, the reason you're getting weird string in your `span` is that you're using `append` of jQuery. It tries to append a new element so if you just want to concatenate strings, use `text` method.

Above points indicate that your code does not work as intended but it's hard to guess what you really want to do with your code and question. Below snippet is only for showing that binding function to the `keydown` event can prevent getting duplicated characters so it also may not work as you intended. You can update your question or with above points, you can fix it by yourself.

```js
$("#textinput").click(function(){
    //setCursor("textinput",0);
    $(this).css("opacity","0.5");
})

$("#textinput").keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var keyCode=e['originalEvent']['keyCode'];
    $(this).css("opacity","1");
    if(keyCode==37 || keyCode==38 || keyCode==39|| keyCode==40){
    
    }else{
        var x=$(this).text();
        x=x.replace("Write HEre","");
        var len=x.length;
        if(len==1){
            if(keyCode==51){
                $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post highlighted-textbox" ></span>');
            }else{
                $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post normal-textbox" ></span>');
            }
        }else{
            if(keyCode==51){
                $("#show-text").append('<span contenteditable class="text-post highlighted-textbox" ></span>');
            } 
        }

        var items=$(".text-post");
        var tot=items.length;
        var span=$(items[tot-1]);
        span.text(span.text()+e['originalEvent']['key'])

        $(this).html($("#show-text"));
        //Funtion for setting cursor
//      setCursor2();
    }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div style="height: 50px; border: 1px solid black;" id="textinput" contenteditable>
<div class="post-placeholder">Write HEre</div>
<div id="show-text"></div></div>
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. I want to create a post box where the input values will be styled differently. If anyone press # then the input values will be styled differently until someone type space.